# The formatter threw an exception while trying to deserialize the message: There was an error while trying to deserialize parameter

Tags: components, tridion

I had developed a custom tool to create components on Tridion.  Using core service i am creating the components.  I tested this application using small text files, it worked fine.
Now i am running my tool to create components for the actual content.  For second file it is giving following error:
"The formatter threw an exception while trying to deserialize the message: There was an error while trying to deserialize parameter http://www.sdltridion.com/ContentManager/CoreService/2011:deltaData. The InnerException message was 'There was an error deserializing the object of type Tridion.ContentManager.Data.IdentifiableObjectData. Reference to undeclared entity 'nbsp'. Line 21, position 12.'.  Please see InnerException for more details.

My file contains a 'nbsp' in between.  Schema for which this component is getting created is a single field of type RTF.

Please suggest me how to resolve this issue.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

The issue is that you're trying to insert HTML into XML.
Replace your `&nbsp;` with `&#160;` and that should fix it.

Comment: Tridion RTF is XHTML, not HTML - make sure your content complies to this, and you should be all good. Tidy is a good library for this, and you can see a sample of using here: http://nunolinhares.blogspot.com/2011/06/importing-content-into-tridion.html